# Vite React PWA updates service worker but doesn't update cached data on production

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, vite, service-worker

We have a Vite React PWA program, which in the production version is not updated instantly after the server and application update the cache information on users' devices, and only after the user manually refreshes or clears their cache, the new version receives

Also, methods such as "prompt" and "autoUpdate" do not work at all

Also, the answer in the link below didn't work because we use CI/CD and have a merge conflict problem

https://dev.to/ammartinwala52/clear-cache-on-build-for-react-apps-1k8j

```js
export default defineConfig({
    define: {
        "process.env": {},
    },
    server: {
        open: false,
    },
    plugins: [
        react(),
        svgr({
            exportAsDefault: true,
            svgrOptions: {},
        }),
        tsconfigPaths(),
        VitePWA({
            registerType: "autoUpdate",
            workbox: {
                skipWaiting: true,
                clientsClaim: true,
            },
            devOptions: {
                enabled: true,
            },
            includeAssets: ["favicon.ico", "apple-touch-icon.png", "mask-icon.svg"],
            manifest: {
                name: "site_name",
                short_name: "site_name",
                description: "site_description",
                theme_color: "hsl(192,97%,56%)",
                background_color: "#ffffff",
                orientation: "portrait",
                display: "standalone",
                scope: "/",
                start_url: "/panel",
                icons: [
                    {
                        src: "pwa-64x64.png",
                        sizes: "64x64",
                        type: "image/png",
                    },
                    {
                        src: "pwa-192x192.png",
                        sizes: "192x192",
                        type: "image/png",
                    },
                    {
                        src: "pwa-512x512.png",
                        sizes: "512x512",
                        type: "image/png",
                        purpose: "any",
                    },
                    {
                        src: "maskable-icon-512x512.png",
                        sizes: "512x512",
                        type: "image/png",
                        purpose: "maskable",
                    },
                ],
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```